# What is this cylinder like part?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification, pneumatic

I found a pair of these among some parts I bought. [image: cylinder] It looks like some sort of cylinder, which could hold an axle for a piston.

Is that correct, and how would I use it then?

Comment: Dude, that's the piece of resistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one half of a "hydraulic" cylinder used like in the bucket of [7685-1: Dozer](http://brickset.com/sets/7685-1/Dozer).

This element is [Fric. Element, Cylinder](http://brickset.com/parts/4494486) and used often used in combination with [Stick 6M W/Flange](http://brickset.com/parts/4538721)

Answer (score 1):

This, at least as far as my experience goes, is used simply to create extra friction in joints; to make something poseable yet stiff and able to hold its position. Sorry no pic, but a good example is the 8996 Scorpio XV1, a walking machine that uses these to keep the legs stationary unless you actually want to move them.